# Yii2 возвращает NULL для пустых полей в БД

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Вытаскиваю список полей с БД

```
$this->model->getAttributes()
```

Получаю

```
array(6) {
  ["category_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["slug"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  NULL
```

А теперь вопрос почему  возвращает NULL, если в БД тип поля NOT NULL ? Почему просто не вернуть пустую строку(которая собственно мне и нужна) ? В чем логика такого поведения ?

У меня проверка стоит в модели

```
[['name', 'content', 'category_id'], 'required'],
```

В итоге он спокойно сохраняет эти NULL обратно в БД o_O

Как получить заветные пустые строки, вместо NULL ?

Версия Yii 2.0.13.1(stable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброе утро!

 Так происходит потому что поля вашего БД в классе модели отмечаются как свойства. И если в базе поле пустое оно принимается как false и не записывается в модель и поэтому поле останется как не определенное то есть null. Это можно довольно просто исправить.

## Пример:

```
class Model extends yii\db\ActiveRecord {
    public $id;
    /** 
       В итоге если в БД это поле будет пустым то вы получаете
       пустую строку... 
    */
    public $some_string_field = '';

    // Другие методы моделя
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, я понял вашу мысль, попробую прописать в правилах валидации значение по умолчанию. Правда не очень практично это все это получается.